# Adding SQS redrive policy using AWS CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, unix, jenkins, amazon-sqs

I am trying to set redrive policy for SQS using the AWS CLI Command below , but seeing an error related to redrive JSON. Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

```
redrive_policy="{\"RedrivePolicy\":{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"$dlq_arn\",\"maxReceiveCount\":\"15\"}}"
```

**AWS CLI COMMAND**

```
aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url https://queue.amazonaws.com/12345678/test-queue --attributes $redrive_policy --region=us-east-1
```

**Error Message**

> Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter
>   Attributes.RedrivePolicy, value: OrderedDict([(u'deadLetterTargetArn',
>   u'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:dlq'), (u'maxReceiveCount', u'15')]),
>   type: , valid types:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried just creating the JSON in a separate file and passing it as an argument to your AWS CLI command? I find it's difficult to get all of the escaping correct when passing the JSON as a parameter. So you'd basically do it as the example shows in the AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/set-queue-attributes.html#examples

1. So first you'd create a new file called "set-queue-attributes.json" like so:

```
    {
      "DelaySeconds": "10",
      "MaximumMessageSize": "131072",
      "MessageRetentionPeriod": "259200",
      "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "20",
      "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:80398EXAMPLE:MyDeadLetterQueue\",\"maxReceiveCount\":\"1000\"}",
      "VisibilityTimeout": "60"
    }
```

2. Then run the command like this:

```
aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/80398EXAMPLE/MyNewQueue --attributes file://set-queue-attributes.json --region=us-east-1
```

Comment: Thanks , I just figured that I missed the double quotes for redrive policy. It worked fine after I added that

Comment: Any tips on how to remove it afterwards? I tried omitting the `RedrivePolicy` field from the JSON but no luck so far...

Comment: @PunterVicky - I am trying to do the exact thing with the Policy attribute.  Getting an identical error.  What did you fix?

Comment: @JDBennett it’s been quite a while but I believe I removed the double quotes when assigning the value to redrive_policy variable

Comment: I got it figured out.  It is the double quotes - need to use single quotes wrapping escaped json.  Double quotes remove the escaping and turn it back into proper json.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to run in the same command you can use this example:

```
aws sqs set-queue-attributes \
--queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/80398EXAMPLE/MyNewQueue \
--attributes '{
    "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:80398EXAMPLE:MyDeadLetterQueue\",\"maxReceiveCount\":\"1000\"}",
    "MessageRetentionPeriod": "259200",
    "VisibilityTimeout": "90"
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Three Methods to achieve this:

> Note: The solutions also work on any other AWS CLI commands that require a stringified JSON

#### 1. Using the Command-line JSON processor `jq` (Recommended)

This method is recommended because of many reasons:

- I've found `jq` a handy tool to use when working with AWS CLI as the need to stringify JSON comes up quite frequently.

> Install for Ubuntu: `sudo apt install jq`
>
> Basic Options:
>
> - `jq -R`: Returns the stringified JSON
> - `jq -c`: Eliminates spacing and newline characters

The benefit is that you can write JSON as JSON and Pipe the result into the `jq -R` command.

**Method 1:**

```s
aws sqs set-queue-attributes \
    --queue-url "https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/IAMEXAMPLE12345678/ExampleQueue" \
    --attributes RedrivePolicy=$(echo '{"maxReceiveCount":500,"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:IAMEXAMPLE12345678:ExampleDeadLetterQueue"}' | jq -R)
```

OR if you have a `sqs-redrive-policy.json` file:

**Method 2:**

**In `sqs-redrive-policy.json`**,

```json
{
  "maxReceiveCount": 500,
  "deadLetterTargetArn": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:IAMEXAMPLE12345678:ExampleDeadLetterQueue"
}
```

**Run in Command Line:**

```s
   aws sqs set-queue-attributes \
    --queue-url "https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/IAMEXAMPLE12345678/ExampleQueue" \ 
    --attributes RedrivePolicy=$(cat ~/path/to/file/sqs-redrive-policy.json | jq -c | jq -R)
```

- As you can see the second benefit is that you can isolately modify only the `--redrive-policy` without having to touch any of the other attributes.

> **Common Confusion**: A confusion is the name `set-queue-attributes` (it would be better named `put-queue-attributes`). as it doesn't overwrite all attributes but only overwrites the attributes mentioned with the command. So if you already set a `Policy` attribute earlier during `create-queue`, this will not overwrite the `Policy` to null. In other words, this is safe to use.

---

#### 2. Using a stringified JSON

This is a pain to be honest, and I avoid this.

```s
aws sqs set-queue-attributes \
--queue-url "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/IAMEXAMPLE12345678/ExampleQueue" \
--attributes '{
    "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:IAMEXAMPLE12345678:ExampleDeadLetterQueue\",\"maxReceiveCount\":\"500\"}",
}'
```

#### 3. Use a filePathURL to the JSON file for `attributes.json` NOT `sqs-redrive-policy.json`

This is my last preference.

**Reason**:

- This means setting all the attributes specified in the `attributes.json` file again at a single go.
- Doesn't escape the pain of writing stringified JSON as text.

**In `attributes.json`**,

```
{
  "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:IAMEXAMPLE12345678:ExampleDeadLetterQueue\", \"maxReceiveCount\":\"5\"}"
}
```

**Run in command line**:

```s
aws sqs set-queue-attributes \
    --queue-url "https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/IAMEXAMPLE12345678/ExampleQueue" \
    --attributes file:///home/yourusername/path/to/file/attributes.json
```

---